# Hosted Continuous Integration options for .NET to Azure

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-cloud-services

I'm looking for a hosted continuous integration platform to build and deploy .NET applications to Microsoft Azure Cloud Services.

I have searched and searched but can anyone recommend a good comparison article or even recommend the best options so I can do my own research? Even a top 5 list would be great or some recommendations.

Thanks

Robert